# Pass environment variables to clean chroot in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, environment-variables, chroot

I am writing a PKGBUILD for Arch Linux. The package is large and compressing/uncompromising it take considerable time for limited space savings and I would like to turn it off while I am writing the PKGBUILD. If I do

```
PKGEXT='.pkg.tar' makepkg
```

I get an uncompressed package. I cannot manage to pass `PKGEXT` to the clean chroot used by `makechrootpkg`. For example,

```
PKGEXT='.pkg.tar' makechrootpkg -cur $chroot
```

leads to an `xz` compressed package. I believe `makechrootpkg` calls `makepkg` as

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER env SRCDEST="$SRCDEST" BUILDDIR="$builddir" \
        makepkg --config="$copydir/etc/makepkg.conf" --verifysource -o
```

Is there a way to pass `PKGEXT` so that it is seen by `makepkg`?

Answer (score 0):

Just put it somewhere inside the PKGBUILD but outside of prepare(), build() and package().

When done just remove it.